# OpenCL: Help parsing cl code for JIT compilation

Tags: parsing, opencl, jit

I have a bit of .cl code that I am trying to compile using the OpenCL C++ API. I keep getting JIT compilation errors for the following bit of code that I found online (for random number generation).
The definition of the function in CL language is:

```
uint2 MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64(uint2 curr, ulong A, ulong M, ulong distance)
{
    ulong m=MWC_PowMod64(A, distance, M);
    ulong x=curr.x*(ulong)A+curr.y;
    x=MWC_MulMod64(x, m, M);
    return (uint2)((uint)(x/A), (uint)(x%A));
}
```

The error LLVM gives me is:

```
<program source>:128:2: error: conflicting types for 'MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64'
<program source>:54:7: note: previous definition is here
uint2 MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64(uint2 curr, ulong A, ulong M, ulong distance)
      ^
<program source>:133:12: error: returning '__uint2' from a function with incompatible result type 'int'
    return (uint2)((uint)(x/A), (uint)(x%A));
```

This function is also used in the bit of code here:

```
uint2 tmp = MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64((uint2)(s->x,s->c), (ulong)(MWC64X_A), (ulong)(MWC64X_M), distance);
```

For some reason, it doesn't like `(uint2)((uint)(x/A), (uint)(x%A))` and thinks I am trying to force-return an int into an unsigned int2. I am aware that during the parsing, the generated source code lines end with an escape character '\'.

Could this be a reason for the errors I am getting below? And more importantly, how do I overcome it, what type of special chars shall I filter during the scanning of the source code?

Thanks,
Amine

Comment: The OpenCL code looks fine. Is there a second function named `MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64` but with different return type? How do you embed the OpenCL code in C++ (raw string / stringification / reading from separate `.cl` file)?

Comment: I stringify the content of the .cl files: the definition of MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64 is in one file which I stringify first, then append the remaining source code to this string. There is no other definition of this function. If you know of any other approach to 'parsing' the code in Xcode that would prevent this nightmare of char parsing, I would be grateful. thanks

Comment: I'd look at solving the `conflicting types for 'MWC_SkipImpl_Mod64'` error first. Do you perhaps need to declare the function prototype before using it? Or have you done that but the prototype declaration (line 54) doesn't match?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the reason why the above wasn't compiling: the JIT compiler didn't see any kernel function to compile and was throwing me an error -11.

Case closed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The way you read the `.cl` files to string seems to be the issue. Probably the escape character at the end of each line. Try reading the files with this:

```c
#include <string>
#include <fstream> // read/write files
string read_file(const string path) { // takes filepath as input, returns content of file as string
    ifstream file(path, ios::in);
    const string r((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    file.close();
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I used your function for file reading, but have another question: the code I got has a few comment lines above some functions (//.....). Does the cl compiler in llvm understand that it needs to ignore them - as in the case of any other language ? If not, then I suspect this could also be throwing the JIT compiler off. thanks

Comment: Yes, the cl compiler understands the // syntax for comments and ignores them. It's a derivative of C99 after all. You can also do #ifdef preprocessor blocks or #define macros/constants within the OpenCL code.

Comment: I was missing the keyword kernel in front of the defined kernels so obviously there was nothing to compile! I had imported someone else's code and forgot he hadn't defined any 'kernels'. My bad!